# Chrome package app access to media files

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

I have google chrome package app.

I need to read locally saved photo and video and give them up to the HTML page.

How can I do this?

I try:

```
chrome.mediaGalleries.getMediaFileSystems(
  {interactive: 'no'},
  function(mediaFileSystems){
    mediaFileSystems.forEach(
      function(item, indx, arr){
        var mData = chrome.mediaGalleries.getMediaFileSystemMetadata(item);
        console.log(mData);
      });
  });
```

But console remains empty.

Comment: What issue are you having with the code that that you have tried?

Comment: @guest271314
I had edit question

Comment: Did you download the packaged app or build the app from scratch?

Comment: Are you using a modified version of the Media Gallery Sample from Chrome Web Store?

Comment: @guest271314 I download an app through the store because I need use chrome.enterprise.

Comment: @guest271314 Tnx I'll go see it

Comment: Encountered a [bug](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/issues/476) using the Media Gallery Sample from Chrome Web Store